# Можно ли на одной страинце использовать несколько вебпак сборок?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, frontend

У меня на одной web странице несколько react приложений (отдельных кусков функциональности), для каждого есть своя сборка webpack (т.е. это не одна сборка из нескольких бандлов, а именно две разные сборки webpack со своими собственными бандлами, runtime-main и т.д., которые ничего не знают друг про друга и имеют разные конфиги, но правда юзают местами общие глобальные объекты). И сейчас когда они обе загружаются на страницу, то происходят ошибки js и всё ломается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, это я где то ошибся, или webpack в принципе, не позволяет загружать js из двух разных сборок на одну страницу?

Comment: и че это такое на выходе должно быть?

Comment: @RavenTheX 'на выходе', в смысле какой ответ хочу получить? Хочу узнать гарантирует ли подефолту webpack, что если подключить несколько его разных сборок на страницу, то они сами по себе не будут конфликтовать